# RabbitMQ Consume message and requeue after compare other messages in the same queue

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I need to consume 100 messages in one time and then I need to compare 100 messages with some condition if not match I will put the message that doesn't match back to the queue.

My idea is

I keep 100 messages into a variable/memory to do a comparison process if found messages 10th and 50th not match condition, then I will put it back to the queue to process next time.

Is it possible to do in RabbitMQ architecture?

Thanks,
Hiko

Comment: Can you provide more information about the match? Seems like you're trying to "group" the messages based on a given criteria. The approches available will vary depending on how many possible values for the criteria, and whether the publisher can or cannot alter the message properties based on the criteria.

Comment: Example: Data is a JSON format
Msg1 => { ‘A’: ‘001’}
Msg2 => { ‘B’: ‘001’}
Msg3 => { ‘C’: ‘001’}
Msg4 => { ‘B’: ‘002’}
Msg5 => { ‘C’: ‘003’}
Msg6 => { ‘A’: ‘002’}

I will reverse value to key to the final structure is
{‘001’ : [‘A’,’B’,’C’],
 ‘002’ : [‘A’,’B’],
 ‘003’ : [‘C’]}
If no ‘A’ in array, I will reject and requeue in this case I will nack “Msg5” to the queue.

Comment: But how many values are possible? If not too many, you could have the value put as routing key in the exchange (direct), and bindings based on that value to a distinct queue each. That way you'd have your consumer(s) check each queue to see if you have enough messages in, and build your structure when matching your requirements.

Comment: More than 300k values, does it have another option?

Comment: There is always another option. ;) The question is whether it makes sense to try and handle your use case in RabbitMQ or not. Requeuing is definitely possible, but I really do not see how you would go about not locking yourself if you for example reach a point where all the values in the top 100 messages are different.

Comment: Finally, my solution is to write a message to file to prevent data loss and ack the message after do the match process, I send it to another queue to check next time.